# Is it possible for HTML element to ignore CSS from one file?

Tags: html, css

In my template I have an element

```
<div class="main_div">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <!--blablabla-->
</div>
```

I also include two CSS files. I really don't want my div to use CSSes from one of them. Is it possible? I'm trying NOT to use iframes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not from a file, but if you include your files in the right order, you can override a rule.

Comment: But if some property of the element is defined in one file and not defined in second - won't it be used anyway?

Comment: Yes, but in the second file you can create a rule that overrides the rule in the first file. If you don't override it, than it will be honered as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no. The best solution to this would be to rename your classes/ids so they all have unique names instead of having overlapping names in your css files. Also, if it's inheriting h1 styling from both you can try using .main_div h1 { ... } which will override the global h1 in both files.